# I am trying to scale the background image of a TextBox but it is cropped

Tags: c#, wpf, background, textbox

I have a TextBox in which I want to add an image as background. The first try is this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Titulo}" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" Name="txtTitulo" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
         TextAlignment="Center"
         FontSize="30"
         Padding="0,20,0,0"
         FontWeight="Heavy"
         BorderBrush="red"
         BorderThickness="5">
    <TextBox.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Imagenes/Logo (233x251) - fondo  transparente (test).png" AlignmentX="Center"  Stretch="None" AlignmentY="Center">
        </ImageBrush>
    </TextBox.Background>
</TextBox>
```

The result in this case is this:

[image]

If I use this code, that uses transform:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Titulo}" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" Name="txtTitulo" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
         TextAlignment="Center"
         FontSize="30"
         Padding="0,20,0,0"
         FontWeight="Heavy"
         BorderBrush="red"
         BorderThickness="5">
    <TextBox.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Imagenes/Logo (233x251) - fondo  transparente (test).png" AlignmentX="Center"  Stretch="None" AlignmentY="Center">
            <ImageBrush.Transform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" CenterX="0" CenterY="0" />
            </ImageBrush.Transform>
        </ImageBrush>
    </TextBox.Background>
</TextBox>
```

The result is this:

[image]

The image that I want to scale is this:

[image]

It seems that when it scales, reduce the size, but it crops the image to the size of the TextBox.

What I want to do it is scale the image to see the complete image, but I am not be able to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Uniform` as value for the `Stretch` property. Like this:

```
Stretch="Uniform"
```

So, your code would look like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Titulo}" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" Name="txtTitulo" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
         TextAlignment="Center"
         FontSize="30"
         Padding="0,20,0,0"
         FontWeight="Heavy"
         BorderBrush="red"
         BorderThickness="5">
    <TextBox.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Imagenes/Logo (233x251) - fondo  transparente (test).png" AlignmentX="Center"  Stretch="Uniform" AlignmentY="Center"/>
    </TextBox.Background>
</TextBox>
```

The `Uniform` value makes the image fill all the available space while keeping its original scale.

Comment: As a side note, because you were using `None` as value for the `Stretch` property, your image was keeping its original fixed size. So if you would scale your textbox, the image would not scale together, because it has a fixed size.

Comment: By reading again your question, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want the image the fit inside the textbox (the planet image inside the textbox) or do you want the image to show out of the textbox bounds (the textbox inside the planet image)?

The solution I posted above makes the image fit inside the textbox (the planet image keeps inside the textbox).